# IGDB API how to sort games by popularity with Python

Tags: python, api

I am pulling data from IGDB API and am unable to sort 'Game' by 'popularity' in descendant order. This is the little info on IGDB documentation on how to do it:

[IGDB documentation info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T80CA.png)

I am trying the following code in Python:

```
import requests
import json
import csv

settings = {'fields' : ['age_ratings,aggregated_rating,aggregated_rating_count,alternative_names,artworks,bundles,category,checksum,collection,cover,created_at,dlcs,expansions,external_games,first_release_date,follows,franchise,franchises,game_engines,game_modes,genres,hypes,involved_companies,keywords,multiplayer_modes,name,parent_game,platforms,player_perspectives,popularity,pulse_count,rating,rating_count,release_dates,screenshots,similar_games,slug,standalone_expansions,status,storyline,summary,tags,themes,time_to_beat,total_rating,total_rating_count,updated_at,url,version_parent,version_title,videos,websites'],
            'limit':'500',
            'sort popularity' : 'desc'}

r = requests.get('https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/', headers = {'user-key':'XXXXXX'}, params = settings)

data = r.json()

data
```

However, the data I am getting is not sorted by popularity in any way.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

[IGDB API documentation](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#about) states that most of the requests use the POST method. It looks like GET requests work as well and some of the parameters like `fields` can be passed as GET parameters. But I found no way to pass `sort` parameters in this way. So you need to use POST requests and pass these parameters as POST data:

```
headers = {'user-key': 'XXXXXX'}
data = 'fields name,popularity;sort popularity desc;'
r = requests.post('https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/', data=data, headers=headers)
```